# Proving that g is coercive and strictly convex

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, coercive

Hello can someone help me understand this?

Suppose we have $g(a) =a^4+a^3+2a^2+a+1$. Prove that g is coercive and strictly convex on R. Therefore, g has a unique global minimizer a*.

Comment: It is enough to show that g is strictly convex and g goes to infinity as a goes to infinity or negative infinity.  You do not actually have to show g is coercive, which may make the problem a bit easier.  g obviously diverges in both directions.